# Get only the task id or attribute from aws-cli's response json

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

I can get the task id by this command.

```
$aws ecs list-tasks --cluster mycluster

{
    "taskArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:142324134231:task/mycluster/44645ae88f294ed9af3f4d809b3f1721",
        "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:142324134231:task/mycluster/73af9f9645d2412bba1344bf0e362fd5"
    ]
}
```

then I copy and paste task id and exec command.

```
aws ecs execute-command \
    --cluster mycluster \
    --task 44645ae88f294ed9af3f4d809b3f1721 \
    --container DjangoContainer \
    --interactive \
    --command "/bin/bash"
```

Is there any way to do this automatically?

It's the problem of shell script or do they have any function like this in aws-cli?

(for example (it's fake))

```
$aws ecs list-tasks --cluster mycluster --show-taskonly
44645ae88f294ed9af3f4d809b3f1721
```

So,my current idea is using php Regular expressions to get the id from the response, and compose new command.

However it dose'nt sound cool.

Is there any good practice?

Comment: Since you are mentioning PHP, it is not clear to me whether you are interested in a PHP solution or as a bash program. You neither tagged your question with php nor with bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the IDs only, you can use  [--query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side):

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster JAJP1LFGTN075  --query "taskArns" --output text
```